# Google Map API: How to display map marker with array from PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use an array in `PHP` to be `var locations` in javascript. This is my array :

```
Array (
      [0] => Array (
          [0] => 001
          [1] => A
          [2] => 98
          [3] => -8.0092722
          [4] => 110.2965559
      )
      [1] => Array (
          [0] => 003
          [1] => C
          [2] => 90
          [3] => -7.9021438
          [4] => 110.3735387
      )
)
```

And i'm trying to pass that array using `json_encode` like below :

```
var markers = <?php json_encode($setarray); ?>
```

The last one, this is my code to create marker :

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {  
   pos = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][3], markers[i][4]);
   bounds.extend(pos);
   marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: pos,
       map: map
   });
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
       return function() {
           infowindow.setContent(markers[i][0]);
           infowindow.open(map, marker);
       }
  })(marker, i));
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }
 }
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I'm pretty sure my problem is when i try to pass the array to javascript, can you help me? Actually this is my first time i use javascript, and i'm not pretty familiar with it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass a php variable in javascript you have to echo the variable var `jsonMarkers = <?php echo json_encode($setarray); ?>`

Also to convert it to the desired JSON object you have to do this

```
var markers = JSON.parse(jsonMarkers);
```

You can then use like this

```
markers[i][j];
```